# Invalid content type for images (.net core sdk 2.1)

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

We are in the process of migrating our project from .net core sdk 1.0 to 2.1. So far so good and I have been able to deploy the project to staging environment but missing images are keeping me stumped. All the images exist on the server and were rendered just fine with .net core sdk 1.0 but it seems that the mime type for the images is wrongly send from server as text/html when migrated to 2.1 and I guess that could be the reason why I keep on getting 500 error. Here's how my project files look:

**.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
  <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
  <AssemblyName>GoalEnvision.Public</AssemblyName>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <PackageId>GoalEnvision.Public</PackageId>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="wwwroot\**\*;Views\**\*;Areas\**\Views\**\*.cshtml;Resources\**\*">
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="migrationsettings.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="AbTestMaster" Version="1.2.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="7.0.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="BundlerMinifier.Core" Version="2.8.391" />
  <PackageReference Include="CommonMark.NET" Version="0.15.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="EPPlus" Version="4.5.2.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="MaxMind.GeoIP2" Version="2.10.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.4" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="2.1.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="2.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.3" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.3" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="2.1.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="2.1.3" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session" Version="2.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.4" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.4">
    <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.4">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="2.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="2.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="2.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="murmurhash-signed" Version="1.0.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Optimizely.SDK" Version="1.3.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="9.3.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" Version="3.2.6" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" Version="5.2.6" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" Version="2.2.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Collections" Version="4.3.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" Version="5.2.6" />
  <PackageReference Include="Sendgrid" Version="9.10.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="iTextSharp" Version="5.5.13" />
  <PackageReference Include="itextsharp.xmlworker" Version="5.5.11" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net472' ">
  <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
  <Reference Include="System.Web" />
  <Reference Include="System" />
  <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using GoalEnvision.Public.DAL;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using GoalEnvision.Public.Areas.Admin.Models;
using GoalEnvision.Public.DAL.Initializer;
using GoalEnvision.Public.DAL.Repositories;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using GoalEnvision.Public.Helpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles;

namespace GoalEnvision.Public
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddDbContext<GoalEnvisionDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(this.Configuration.GetSection("connectionString").Value));
                services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(config => {
                    // Config here
                    config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                    config.Password = new PasswordOptions
                    {
                        RequireDigit = true,
                        RequireNonAlphanumeric = false,
                        RequireUppercase = false,
                        RequireLowercase = true,
                        RequiredLength = 8,
                    };
                })
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<GoalEnvisionDbContext>()
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                // Cookie settings
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                // If the LoginPath isn't set, ASP.NET Core defaults 
                // the path to /Account/Login.
                options.LoginPath = new PathString("/admin/users/login");
                // If the AccessDeniedPath isn't set, ASP.NET Core defaults 
                // the path to /Account/AccessDenied.
                options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/admin/users/login");
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });

            services.AddDirectoryBrowser();
            services.AddMvc();

            // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache.
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                // One day for Optimizely User ID cookie
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(86400);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            });

            services.AddRouting(options => {
                options.LowercaseUrls = true;
                options.AppendTrailingSlash = true;
            });

            services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<INewsRepository, NewsRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IImageRepository, ImageRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IVideoRepository, VideoRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IRegistrationRepository, RegistrationRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IBlobStorageUtility, BlobStorageUtility>();

            services.AddScoped<IEmailUtility, EmailUtility>(provider => new EmailUtility(this.Configuration.GetSection("sendGridApiKey").Value, this.Configuration.GetSection("GoalEnvisionSettings:SiteBaseUrl").Value));

            services.Configure<GoalEnvisionSettings>(options => this.Configuration.GetSection("GoalEnvisionSettings").Bind(options));
            services.Configure<BlobStorageSettings>(options => this.Configuration.GetSection("blobStorage").Bind(options));
            Translations.Translations.Initialize();
            AutoMapperSetup.Initialize();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            //404 error
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                await next();
                if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
                {
                    context.Request.Path = "/not-found";
                    await next();
                }
            });

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
                {
                    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor,

                    // IIS is also tagging a X-Forwarded-For header on, so we need to increase this limit, 
                    // otherwise the X-Forwarded-For we are passing along from the browser will be ignored
                    ForwardLimit = 2
                });
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                //for generic errors
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
            }

            // Set up custom content types - associating file extension to MIME type
            var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
            // Add new mappings
            provider.Mappings[".myapp"] = "application/x-msdownload";
            provider.Mappings[".htm3"] = "text/html";
            provider.Mappings[".image"] = "image/png";

            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                ContentTypeProvider = provider,
                OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
                {
                    ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", "public,max-age=1209600");    //14 days=1209600
                }
            });

            using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                using (var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<GoalEnvisionDbContext>())
                {
                    context.Database.Migrate();
                    context.EnsureSeedData(app.ApplicationServices).Wait();
                }
            }
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(name: "areaRoute", 
                    template: "{area:exists}/{controller=News}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "WithoutHomeInUrl",
                    template: "{action}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
                );

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace GoalEnvision.Public
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

Snapshot of the project structure
[image]

Interesting bit is that css, font and js files appear alright. Here's my project url (https://goalenvisionpublic-test.azurewebsites.net/sv/) and the sample image that is missing (https://goalenvisionpublic-test.azurewebsites.net/images/home/cover_test_now_sv.png)

Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Comment: Fail to reproduce your issue, could you try to reproduce your issue with [StartupFileType](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/blob/f06faa164f0cb3eb19e9b928b066248574886858/StaticFilePro/StartupFileType.cs#L32)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing a similar issue, the reason for the problem was duplicate staticContent tags. Apparently .net core 2.1 transforms the web.config and adds its own tag for managing the caching time. So additional tag resulted in invalid configuration file. All I had to do was to remove my own tags:

```
<location path="images">
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
<location path="fonts">
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Our project is targeting 4.7.2 version